# Angular / Spring Boot problem : No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present

Tags: angular, spring-boot, cors

hope all are doing great.

I was doing a project that registered a client account. However, it faces CORS policy issues:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8085/client/sign-up' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
signup-client.component.ts:33
```

```
POST http://localhost:8085/client/sign-up net::ERR_FAILED
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m894Q.png)

Here is my Angular auth.service.ts

```
import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';

const BASIC_URL = 'http://localhost:8085/';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  registerClient(signupRequestDTO: any): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post(BASIC_URL + "client/sign-up", signupRequestDTO);
  }

  registerCompany(signupRequestDTO: any): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post(BASIC_URL + "company/sign-up", signupRequestDTO);
  }

  private handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
    if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
      // A client-side or network error occurred. Handle it accordingly.
      console.error('An error occurred:', error.error.message);
    } else {
      // The backend returned an unsuccessful response code.
      // The response body may contain clues as to what went wrong.
      console.error(
        `Backend returned code ${error.status}, ` +
        `body was: ${error.error}`);
    }
    // Return an observable with a user-facing error message.
    return throwError('Something bad happened; please try again later.');
  }
}
```

And here is my Springboot SimpleCorsFilter

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.Ordered;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;

import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;


@Configuration
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class SimpleCorsFilter implements Filter {

    @Value("${app.client.url}")
    private String clientAppUrl = " ";

    public SimpleCorsFilter() {

    }



    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;

        String originHeader = request.getHeader("Origin");

        // Allow requests from the actual Origin value if it's not null
        if (originHeader != null) {
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", originHeader);
        }
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, PUT, OPTIONS, DELETE");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*");

        if ("OPTIONS".equalsIgnoreCase(request.getMethod())) {
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        } else {
            chain.doFilter(req, res);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {

    }


    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {

    }

}
```

Pls let me know what do you think. Any suggestion will be helpful. Thanks

I expect to send the API success and will see the new client in my MySQL DB